# Angular find, multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am searching for input fields with specific classes.

So it currently looks like this:

```
angular.element(document).find('input.ng-invalid-utf');
```

This works fine. However if I want to search for multiple classes, like

```
angular.element(document).find('input.ng-invalid-utf, textarea.ng-invalid-utf, input.ng-invalid-max');
```

It doesn't and I don't know where to search.

Comment: What purposes is the angular.element().find for? What are you trying to achieve? This might not be the best way to achieve it, for example manipulating data on the controller to display further on, you wouldn't need to get the element but you'd want the model you use (which is easily available on the controller, for example).

Comment: Basically our company has a rather complex application with some nested forms. The requirement is, when the user clicks 'Save' I check which inputs and textareas are invalid. I guess it's easier to just search for the ng-invalid classes, then to iterate over form.$errors because the Object I get there is too complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `querySelectorAll` .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

```
element[0].querySelectorAll('.ng-invalid, .ng-valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to update the value of some element by querying the elements, I would suggest not to do it.
use

```
//in your controller
$scope.name = 'example';
//in your html
<input type='text' ng-model="name" />
```

Comment: Basically our company has a rather complex application with some nested forms. The requirement is, when the user clicks 'Save' I check which inputs and textareas are invalid. I guess it's easier to just search for the ng-invalid classes, then to iterate over form.$errors because the Object I get there is too complex